# c-extension Python memory leak,why?

Tags: python, c

recently i have a project write by C,and extension Python in ,
i call Python in a while loop,and the result is the memory grows never stop.

here is the code:

```
main
{
   while True {
      if( SUCCESS != PyInit())
      {
          return -1;
      }
      PyDone();
      usleep(1000);
      } 
}


int PyInit(void)
{
         Py_Initialize(); 
         if(!Py_IsInitialized())
         {
              printf("PyInit: Python Init fail!\n");
              return FAILURE;
         }
         else
         {
              printf( "Python Init succ!\n");
              return SUCCESS;

         }

}

void PyDone(void)
{
         Py_Finalize();
}
```

and at last my english is poor,hope i have described this question clearly.

Comment: Try running with valgrind. Additionally, CPython's garbage collector holds onto memory as long as it cares to the last time I experimented with it.

Comment: @Joran Beasley  i will try what you say.

Comment: @Eric Urban in this case ,how can we do CPython.~

Comment: @Joran Beasley  have not yet..

Comment: @JoranBeasley `aczInVal` has automatic storage duration. That means the array will be automatically released when the end of it's scope is reached. Attempting to "manually release" that would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @modifiable    lvalue now i had modify the code ,can you give me a suggestion(as only run the code here also makes the memory leak).thank you @!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (;;) {
    PyInitialize();
    if (PyIsInitialized()) {
        PyFinalize();
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If your code resembles this, and there appears to be memory leaking, then the python implementation is at fault because PyFinalize supposedly "frees all memory allocated by the Python interpreter". The python site states, in regards to PyFinalize, "Small amounts of memory allocated by the Python interpreter may not be freed (if you find a leak, please report it)." A search through the python bug tracker for [leak](http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40columns=id%2Cactivity%2Ctitle%2Ccreator%2Cassignee%2Cstatus%2Ctype&%40sort=-activity&%40filter=status&%40action=searchid&ignore=file%3Acontent&%40search_text=leak&submit=search&status=-1%2C1%2C2%2C3) indicates that this hasn't yet been reported, so I suggest reporting this bug to their [bugtracker](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: yeah! i read this in the c-api also,but i just don't know how to report ,and ~